# Update a nested field inside Array or Struct attribute conditionally in PySpark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, aws-glue

In a dataframe in AWS Glue I want to update a nested field inside Array or Struct attribute in PySpark satisfying a particular condition.

I know to update a primitive attribute conditionally like this:

```
dataframe.withColumn('primitive_attribute', when(col("primaryKey") == "someValue", lit(None)).otherwise(col('primitive_attribute')))
```

My expected output format is:

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- addresses: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- street: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- pincode: string (nullable = true)
```

Here I want to update all pincodes in addresses as null for some specific ids.

But, is there any way to update nested field inside Array or Struct ?

Comment: You can use '.' notation like this if it's a struct. ```withColumn('col1.col2', ...)```

Comment: Please show sample input and expected output

Comment: updated in question